# In which file is my Environment supposed to be set

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I just finished setting up my server and stuff.  I need to set my Environments file. I've tried looking for it in config folder on main directory. Still I don't know where the file to set my server Environment is. Can anyone guide my search. I'm lost at this point. Don't know what to do.

Comment: There is no file unless you do some custom code. `ENVIRONMENT` is a constant which is set in `index.php` so modify that logic to your liking

Comment: If I put the constant at development then what causes my site to dispense an index file and not  allow access to browse my site.

Comment: I can't even view my site. Just looking for causes to fix issue. it keeps downloading an index file to set environment. even after I switched to production it continues to download the index.

Comment: This does not sound like a CodeIgniter issue at all. It sounds like your server is not configured properly and is sending the file to you instead of sending it to PHP for processing

Comment: I assume that if you create an `test.php` file then your browser downloads it too, right?

Comment: my site was up and running fine no issues with server, db, at all. 4 days ago. then today this file error reporting issue. I've seen this happen before with my other domain name migration and same source files.

Comment: I could only wonder what someone could do to get around this. This is my best option as I frown upon sharing cpanel credentials to unknown developers.

Comment: Unless you're paying me money then I don't want your cPanel credentials nor anything to do with your website. If you have a hosting provider then call their customer support number and see if they can help you with whatever configuration you need.